# Añadir fondo en swift para ios

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Acabo de comenzar el desarrollo de apps en IOS y la verdad que el cambio desde el java de android es abismal...

Tengo una duda, y es como poder insertar un fondo desde una imagen. Logicamente he podido probar la opcion de poner un IMAGEVIEW y expandirlo para que quede de fondo, pero no creo que sea la mejor de las opciones,espero vuestras respuestas, gracias.

Ademas de esto, como se en que estoy programando? swift1/swift2/swift3? quiero decir, como se cuando mi codigo es de un tipo u otro? Mi XCODE esta actualizado a la ultima version.

Comment: Si tu xcode es la version 8, entonces sera swift 3

Comment: Para añadir una imagen de fondo lo tendrias que hacer desde el main.storyboard

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta Alberto, algun consejo para hacerlo? alguna opcion que lo permita al estilo android con el background src?

Comment: Puedes hechar un vistazo a esta web, vienen ejemplos en swift y uno enconcreto es de imagenes, espero que te sirva: http://www.todoenswift.com/

Comment: gracias, lo voy a mirar...una ultima cosa, entonces si utilizo codigo de swift2 o swift no me lo va a compilar bien el xcode al estar actualizado?

Comment: Si, te puede salir algun error pero te lo corrije automatico el xcode. Si no tambien le puedes dar a: Edit->Convert->To Current Swift Syntax->

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias opciones para hacer lo que quieres.

Una es la que ya dijiste, agregar un `UIImageView` y ponerla de fondo con `self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)`

Otra opción es usar el constructor [`init(patternImage:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621933-init) de la clase `UIColor` y usarlo como `backgroundColor` de la vista:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

Con respecto a la versión de Swift, si estás usando Xcode 8 debería ser Swift 3.0. A no ser que hayas cambiado en los *Build Settings* del proyecto para que quede con *Use Legacy Swift Language Version = Yes*, en cuyo caso estás usando Swift 2.3. Si es Xcode 7, entonces seguramente sea Swift 2.2...

Amplío un poco más. Viendo [esta respuesta de Stack Overflow (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312194/135050), veo que usan `UIGraphics*` para que la imagen se ajuste al tamaño de la vista... Si la imagen ya es del tamaño adecuado, entonces no es necesario. Si no, tal vez lo tengas que hacer.

Comment: lo probare Marcos! muchas gracias!

Comment: Este código: `self.view.sendSubviewToBack()`, no funciona en `swift3`. `Value of type UIView has no member 'sendSubviewToBack'`. En `swift 3` seria: `sendSubview(toBack: )`

Comment: En Swift 3 cambió de nombre: `sendSubview(toBack view: UIView)`